# Weird tipx error

Tags: compiling, programming, tipa

Just for fun I wrote a converter for decimal numbers that prints them in bases < 37:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,hyperref,ifthen}
\usepackage{tipx}

\makeatletter
\newcount\mod

\newcommand*{\modulo}[2]{%
  \mod=#1
  \@tempcnta=#2
  \ifnum\mod<\@tempcnta\else
    \loop
    \advance\mod by -#2
    \unless\ifnum\mod<#2
    \repeat
  \fi}%

\newcount\cnv@quotient \cnv@quotient=0
\newcount\cnv@power \cnv@power=1
\newcount\cnv \cnv=0
\def\comv{}

\newcommand*{\convertdec}[2][2]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\uppercase\relax %if symbols should not be uppercased
  \cnv@quotient=#2
  \whiledo{\cnv@quotient>0}{%
    \modulo{\cnv@quotient}{#1}
    \edef\conv{\uppercase{\basechange{\the\mod}}\conv}
    \divide\cnv@quotient by #1}%
  \texorpdfstring{\conv\textsubscript{#1}}{\conv}
  \endgroup}%
\newcommand{\basechange}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
    0\or 1\or 2\or 3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\or 9\or
    \x \or \xi \or \xii \or \xiii \or \xiv \or \xv \or
    \xvi \or \xvii \or \xviii \or \xix \or \xx \or
    \xxi \or \xxii \or \xxiii \or \xxiv \or \xxv \or
    \xxvi \or \xxvii \or \xxviii \or \xxix \or \xxx \or
    \xxxi \or \xxxii \or \xxxiii \or \xxxiv \or \xxxv\fi}%
\def\x{a}
\def\xi{b}
\def\xii{c}
%and so on
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\convertdec[12]{131}
\end{document}
```

If I change the digit control words like

```
\def\x{$\alpha$}
\def\xi{$\beta$}
```

everything is fine. But, when I say `\def\x{\textturntwo}` the compilation won't terminate; seems to end up in a infinite loop. The strange thing is that the console does not yield a TeX capacity exceeded message. The `.log` file is just incomplete. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Doing `\let\uppercase\relax` is something I can't recommend. The problem is the usual one; you should use `\protected@xdef` and not `\xdef`.

Comment: @egreg, also when grouped inside of a macro?

Comment: I see no group. In any case you should do (in a group) `\let\uppercase\@firstofone`

Comment: @egreg, I see the difference but no advantages/disadvantages comparing both instructions. Before you answer here: do you think this is worth an own question? (Or is there alredy one on SX?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in using `\xdef` instead of `\protected@xdef`; all `\text...` macros in LaTeX cannot be used in the replacement text for `\edef` (and so `\xdef`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,hyperref,ifthen}
\usepackage{tipx}

\makeatletter
\newcount\mod

\newcommand*{\modulo}[2]{%
  \mod=#1
  \@tempcnta=#2
  \ifnum\mod<\@tempcnta\else
    \loop
    \advance\mod by -#2
    \unless\ifnum\mod<#2
    \repeat
  \fi}%

\newcount\cnv@quotient \cnv@quotient=0
\newcount\cnv@power \cnv@power=1
\newcount\cnv \cnv=0
\def\conv{}

%% Switch the comment if you want to uppercase
\let\maybe@uppercase\@firstofone
%\let\maybe@uppercase\uppercase

\newcommand*{\convertdec}[2][2]{%
  \cnv@quotient=#2
  \whiledo{\cnv@quotient>0}{%
    \modulo{\cnv@quotient}{#1}
    \protected@edef\conv{\maybe@uppercase{\basechange{\the\mod}}\conv}
    \divide\cnv@quotient by #1}%
  \texorpdfstring{\conv\textsubscript{#1}}{\conv}
  \let\conv\@empty}%
\newcommand{\basechange}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
    0\or 1\or 2\or 3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\or 9\or
    \x \or \xi \or \xii \or \xiii \or \xiv \or \xv \or
    \xvi \or \xvii \or \xviii \or \xix \or \xx \or
    \xxi \or \xxii \or \xxiii \or \xxiv \or \xxv \or
    \xxvi \or \xxvii \or \xxviii \or \xxix \or \xxx \or
    \xxxi \or \xxxii \or \xxxiii \or \xxxiv \or \xxxv\fi}%
\def\x{\textturntwo}
\def\xi{b}
\def\xii{c}
%and so on
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\convertdec[12]{131}
\end{document}
```

I fixed also the quirk with `\uppercase`: redefining it outside a group is a mistake. And in any case it should be `\let\uppercase\@firstofone` to remove the braces. But it's better to use a different macro that can be redefined at will, instead of redefining a primitive.

[image]

It's much easier in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,xparse,hyperref}
\usepackage{tipx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\convertdec}{O{2}m}
 {
  \ruben_convertdec:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definedigits}{m}
 {
  \ruben_define_digits:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ruben_converted_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ruben_temp_tl
\prop_new:N \l_ruben_digits_prop

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ruben_convertdec:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ruben_converted_tl { \int_to_base:nn { #2 } { #1 } }
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__ruben_converted_tl
   {
    \ruben_use_digit:n { ##1 }
   }
  \texorpdfstring{$\sb{#1}$}{}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ruben_use_digit:n #1
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \l_ruben_digits_prop { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ruben_define_digits:n #1
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_ruben_digits_prop ##1
   }
 }

% initialize
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 36 }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ruben_temp_tl { \int_to_base:nn { #1 } { 36 } }
  \prop_put:NVV  \l_ruben_digits_prop \l__ruben_temp_tl \l__ruben_temp_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definedigits{
  {a}{\textturntwo},
  {b}{\&} % just for showing the syntax
}

\begin{document}
\convertdec[12]{131}
\end{document}
```

Note that this doesn't require particular protections. The digits are initialized to be `0123456789abc` and so on. For changing a particular digit, use a braced pair such as `{c}{C}` in the argument to `\definedigits`, separating braced pairs by a comma as in the example.

Comment: Which property exactly of the `\text...` macros requires "protection"?

Comment: @Ruben All `\text...` macros do assignments, which are not performed in `\edef`.

Comment: Ok, I see. In `tipx` fontselection is happening. I guess it is the same for all the other `\text...`. By the way: where are they defined if not by some package? In `latex.ltx`?