# Incomplete \iffalse using \phantom

Tags: conditionals

Can anyone help me debug the code below? As written, it produces an Incomplete `\iffalse error` on the `\xdef` line on the final iteration. The problem is somehow related to the `\phantom` macro, as `\def\c{0}` works fine. I know there are a couple of conditional tests inside `\phantom`, but I'm not enough of a TeX wizard to figure out what is colliding with what.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\result{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
\StrChar{12345}{\i}[\c]
\ifx\c\empty
\def\c{\phantom{0}}
\fi
\xdef\result{\result\c}}


\stop
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\phantom` can't be used in `\xdef`, because it does assignments.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215424/weird-tipx-error regarding @egreg's comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\phantom` is a fragile command and not safe in an `\edef`. One way to locally make it safe is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\result{}
\let\oldphantom\phantom
\let\phantom\relax
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
\StrChar{12345}{\i}[\c]
\ifx\c\empty
\def\c{\phantom{0}}
\fi
\xdef\result{\result\c}}
\let\phantom\oldphantom
\show\result

\stop
```

Comment: You can simply do `\let\phantom\relax` inside the cycle code, because they are performed in a group.

Comment: This solution works; thanks. I think I understand it, but I want to make sure. The `\let\phantom\relax` essentially makes \phantom an unexpandable noop inside the loop. But when \result is expanded at the end \phantom has its real definition back so it works as expected. Is that about right?

Comment: @Jay yes, exactly

Answer (score 4):

You can't have `\phantom` inside `\xdef`, because it performs assignments.

There are several strategies for avoiding the problem.

**First strategy**: use a `\protected` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,pgffor}

\protected\def\Pzero{\phantom{0}}

\begin{document}

\def\result{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{%
  \StrChar{12345}{\i}[\c]%
  \ifx\c\empty
    \def\c{\Pzero}%
  \fi
  \xdef\result{\result\c}%
}

X\result X

\end{document}
```

The loop can be, more simply,

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{%
  \StrChar{12345}{\i}[\c]%
  \xdef\result{\result\ifx\c\empty\Pzero\else\c\fi}%
}
```

**Second strategy**: use token registers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,pgffor}

\newtoks\mytoks

\begin{document}

\def\result{}
\mytoks={}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{%
  \StrChar{12345}{\i}[\c]%
  \ifx\c\empty
    \global\mytoks=\expandafter{\the\mytoks\phantom{0}}%
  \else
    \global\mytoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\mytoks\c}%
  \fi
}
\edef\result{\the\mytoks}

X\result X

\end{document}
```

**Third strategy**: forget `xstring` and `pgffor` and prefer `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\padnumber}{mmo}
 {% #1 is the final number of digits
  % #2 the given number
  % #3 is an optional macro to store the result in
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \jay_padnumber:nnn { \tl_use:N \l_jay_partial_tl } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \jay_padnumber:nnn { \tl_set_eq:NN #3 \l_jay_partial_tl } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_jay_partial_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \jay_padnumber:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  % store the given number
  \tl_set:Nn \l_jay_partial_tl { #3 }
  \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:N \l_jay_partial_tl < #2 }
   {
    % add as many \phantom{0} as needed
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_jay_partial_tl
     {
      \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - \tl_count:N \l_jay_partial_tl } { \exp_not:N \phantom { 0 } }
     }
   }
  % produce the result or store it
  #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X1234567890 % test

X\padnumber{6}{12345}X

X\padnumber{7}{12345}X

X\padnumber{4}{12345}X

\padnumber{8}{12345}[\result]

\texttt{\meaning\result}

\end{document}
```

We count the items in the argument; if the number of items exceeds the given argument, the number is simply printed (or stored). Otherwise the right number of `\phantom{0}` is added in one step.

[image]