# Phantom does not work without protected keyword in xdef

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, white-space

I'm trying to align labels, but it seems that space has a different width then digits are.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother
%\protected\def\Pzero{\phantom{0}}%
\def\Pzero{\phantom{0}}%

\begin{document}

    \xdef\str{1}%
    \xdef\str{\str\Pzero}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node at (0, 0) {$11\bigcdot \str$};
        \node at (0, 0.5) {$11\bigcdot 11$};
        \node at (0, -0.5) {$22\bigcdot 00$};

        \draw[red, thin] (0, 1) -- (0, -1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

In the code \phantom{0} does not work for some reason

with a log message

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

This is a half-full working version, with protected phantom

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.5]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, intersections}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% note, 
%   0 - is an empty space
%   1 - is an other agent
%   2 - is an edge
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% model parameters
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\memory}{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\visibility}{3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\obscure}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\maxtablelength}{16}

\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
    \newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
    \makeatother

    \def\noAgent{0}%
    \def\agent{1}%
    \def\leftAppend{0}%
    \def\rightAppend{1}%
    \protected\def\Pzero{\phantom{\noAgent}}%

    \newcommand{\CreateVStr}[2]
    {%
        \xdef\str{}%
        \ifnum#1=1%
            \xdef\str{\agent}%
        \else%
            \ifnum#1<\onesidestates%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastseen}{mod(#1, 2) + \agent}%
                \xdef\str{\lastseen}%
            \fi%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zeros}{#1 / 2}%
            \foreach \zero in {1, ..., \zeros}%
            {%
                \ifnum#2=\leftAppend%
                    \xdef\str{\str\noAgent}%
                \else%
                    \xdef\str{\noAgent\str}%
                \fi%
            }%
        \fi%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\emptyspaces}{\visibility - int(#1 / 2) - 1}%
        \ifnum\emptyspaces>0%
            \foreach \zero in {1, ..., \emptyspaces}%
            {%
                \ifnum#2=\leftAppend%
                    \xdef\str{\noexpand\Pzero\str}%
                \else%
                    \xdef\str{\str\noexpand\Pzero}%
                \fi%
            }%
        \fi%
    }%

    \newcommand{\CreateLeftStr}[1]
    {%
        \CreateVStr{#1}{\leftAppend}%
        \xdef\leftstr{\str}%
    }%

    \newcommand{\CreateRightStr}[1]
    {%
        \CreateVStr{#1}{\rightAppend}%
        \xdef\rightstr{\str}%
    }%

    % drawing parameters
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lengthlabelline}{0.8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\labelxoffset}{0.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\labelyoffset}{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tiklabelxoffset}{0.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tiklabelyoffset}{0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellsize}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\above}{0.5+\visibility/20}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scalefactor}{0.8}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % common code
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tableheight}{2^(\memory)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\onesidestates}{ifthenelse(\obscure == 1, 2 * \visibility, 2 ^ (\visibility + 1) - 1)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numberofstates}{\onesidestates ^ 2}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numberoftables}{ceil(\numberofstates / \maxtablelength)}

        \begin{scope}[scale=\cellsize]
            % draw all the tables
            \foreach \tablenum in {1, ..., \numberoftables}
            {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tablelength}{ifthenelse(\tablenum < \numberoftables, \maxtablelength, \numberofstates - (\numberoftables - 1) * \maxtablelength)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{-(\tablenum - 1) * (\tableheight + 1.5)}

                \begin{scope}[yshift=\yoffset cm]
                    \coordinate (left_upper_corner_\tablenum) at (0, \tableheight);
                    \draw (0, 0) grid (\tablelength, \tableheight);
                    \begin{scope}[shift={(left_upper_corner_\tablenum)}]
                        \draw (0, 0) -- ++(135:\lengthlabelline);
                        \node[rotate=-45,scale=0.5] at ($(135:\labelxoffset)+(45:\labelyoffset)$) {input};
                        \node[rotate=-45,scale=0.5] at ($(135:\labelxoffset)+(180+45:\labelyoffset)$) {memory};
                    \end{scope}
                    \foreach \state in { 1, ..., \tableheight}
                    {
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\memorystate}{\state-1}
                        \node (memory_\tablenum_\state) at (0 - \tiklabelyoffset, \tableheight - \state + \tiklabelxoffset) {$\memorystate$};
                    }                   
                \end{scope}
            }

            \ifdim\obscure pt=1 pt%
                % prepare obscured visible state in one dimension :left
                \foreach \leftstate in {1, ..., \onesidestates}
                {
                    \CreateLeftStr{\leftstate}

                    % right part of visible state
                    \foreach \rightstate in {1, ..., \onesidestates}
                    {
                        \CreateRightStr{\rightstate}

                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currentstate}{(\leftstate - 1) * \onesidestates + (\rightstate - 1)}
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tablenum}{ceil((\currentstate + 1) / \maxtablelength)}
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\columnnum}{mod(\currentstate, \maxtablelength)}
                        \begin{scope}[shift={(left_upper_corner_\tablenum)}]
                            \node[above=\above cm, rotate=90, scale=\scalefactor] at (\columnnum + \scalefactor - 0.1, 0) {$\leftstr\bigcdot\rightstr$};
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            \fi%

        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikz` centers the text in the node and “control-space” is not as wide as a digit. In my test, `11\bigcdot 1\hphantom{1}` works

Comment: `\phantom{1}` would be the normal markup (although there are more efficient ways to get the width of the character)

Comment: If `\phantom{1}` doesn't work with *that* code, then you have big problems. Can you be more precise about the real issue?

Comment: If there are always two digits before `\bigcdot`, you can add option `anchor=west` to `tikzpicture` env. This means, now the anchor node.west, rather than node.center, is put at `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Please mark this issue as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217975/incomplete-iffalse-using-phantom

Comment: Since latex2e 2020-10-01, `\phantom` is made robust. Are you using an old latex2e?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, updated everything - still does not work without \protected.

Comment: @dEmigOd The latex2e version is shown In the first line of `.log` file, for example `preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.5`. What is the version on your side?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.21

Comment: @dEmigOd Your latex2e is updated. Can you update your example to use `\phantom` (and make sure it causes problem on your side)?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, updated code - this does not compile, unless i uncomment protected.

Comment: I get a much different error, why are you defining `\str` like that, especially in the second line. What is that `\xdef` suppose to do there?

Comment: @daleif, I'm building a string in some foreach loop (in actual code). This pretty minimal example does not work on my machine

Comment: You cannot fully expand a `\phantom` that does not make any sense as it is a purely typographic element. Perhaps you should try `\noexpand\phantom`. Though, it might be better to explain your real goal, perhaps here is a better solution.

Comment: `\protected@xdef\str{\str\noexpand\Pzero}` is the respect-to-`\protect` version of `\xdef`. Maybe you need this. And, this is more or less equivalent to `\xdef\str{\str\noexpand\Pzero}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, I've added the full version, cause I quite don't understand how should I implement what you are writing

Comment: @dEmigOd Your full example works alright, in which the dots of each table are at the same height. Moreover, since you have used `\protected` in `\protected\def\Pzero{\phantom{\noAgent}}`, `\Pzero` will not expand inside an `\edef`-expansion. Hence the `\noexpand` is `\xdef\str{\noexpand\Pzero\str}` is redundant.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, I thought you have said, that phantom should work without protected (as the linked question suggested in the first place)

Comment: @dEmigOd There is a difference. 1) When used in replacement text of `\def` (or `\gdef`), no commands expand. 2) When used in `\edef` (or `\xdef`), robust commands defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` (this is how `\phantom` defined) expands but robust commands defined with prefix \protected do not. 3) When used in `\protected@xdef`, robust commands defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` works like it is expanded only once. For example, `\xdef\x{\phantom}` defines `\x` to `\protect\phantom␣`. I misunderstood your use case before.